# Error en executeQuery, Intentando conectar con bd en Access

Tags: java, netbeans, ms-access

Estoy empezando con java, intento conectar el programa con una base de datos de access pero me marca este error:

> C:\Users\AndresGarcia\Documents\NetBeansProjects\solin\src\solin\Solin.java:29:error:
>   cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>       ResultSet resultado = (ResultSet) consulta.executeQuery("select * from usuario");
>
>       symbol:   method executeQuery(String)
>
>
> location: variable consulta of type Statement
>
> 1 error
> ```

Esta es mi clase principal:

```
import java.beans.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class Solin {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Conexion conn = new Conexion();

            Statement consulta = (Statement) conn.getConncetion().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultado =  consulta.executeQuery("select * from usuario");

            while (resultado.next()) {
                System.out.println("el codigo es "+resultado.getString("codigo"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    //executeQuery 


}
```

Esta es la Clase conexion:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    private String database ="Solin.accdb";
    private String username ="";
    private String password ="";
    private String url ="jdbc:ucanacess://"+System.getProperty("user.dir").replace("\\","/"+database);

public Connection conn = null;

public Conexion(){

    try{
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}

public Connection getConncetion(){
    return conn;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

}

Comment: Donde esta el error?

Comment: Qué tiene tu clase `Conexion`?

Comment: en "executeQuery", me marca un error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas importando una libreria `Statement` equivocada. Por el código que muestras lo que quieres usar es `java.sql.Statement` y no `java.beans.Statement`.

De ahí que estés haciendo un cast en la siguiente linea:

```
Statement consulta = (Statement) conn.getConncetion().createStatement();
```

Cuando no te debería hacer falta poner `(Statement)` cogiendo el Statement del conector.

Por lo tanto prueba a cambiar el import y quitar el cast de esa linea.